# For a Chef (12.5) Custom Resource, how do I call one action from another and preserve order?

Tags: chef-infra

I am trying to do the following as a custom resource (generalized):

```
action :a do
  resource 'foo' do

  end

  action_b

  resource 'bar' do

  end
end

action :b do

  resource 'xyz' do

  end
end
```

Where I want to trigger action 'b' in the middle of doing other work for action 'a'. What I would expect to happen is that the default action for 'xyz' would occur between the execution of the default action for the 'foo' and 'bar' resources. However, what actually occurs is that the execution of the 'xyz' resource occurs first.

I suspect this is probably has something to do with compile-time vs run-time shenanigans (since this is what causes most of my issues in chef), but I don't know enough about the life cycle of custom resources in order to retain the execution order I'd like.

So the question is... how can I structure this so that action 'b' is executed in the proper order?

Answer (score 0):

This is not really supported, put the stuff inside the `b` action in another helper method and call it from both actions.

Comment: If you could add an example of what that might look like, I would mark this as the answer.